# Number of ways of dividing sum of $n$ numbers into sum of $2$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I got the idea of this question from the book on Calculus by Spivak.

The author states that the operation of adding three numbers *i.e.* $a+b+c$, is actually unambiguous as $a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c$. If we accept this as a fact, we can prove that the operation of adding four numbers *i.e.* $a+b+c+d$ is also unambiguous. The first way in which he proves this is by listing the *five* possible ways in which we can write this expression (or in other words, *parenthesise* or *bracket* this expression) as a sum of two numbers. For example, those five ways can be listed as follows:

$1 - ((a+b)+c)+d$ (where $((a+b)+c)$ is one number and $d$ is another)

$2 - (a+(b+c))+d$

$3 - a+((b+c)+d)$

$4 - a+(b+(c+d))$

$5 - (a+b)+(c+d)$

I am not interested in that proof here, but *the way* in which he wrote these 5 expressions. In fact, he later on states that for 5 numbers, we will have 14 such expressions.

My question is whether we can calculate **the number of ways** in which we can rewrite (or *parenthesise* or *bracket*) the expression $a_1+...+a_n$ as a sum of 2 numbers, for any general value of $n$, in terms of $n$ itself?

Note: It would be great if someone could add additional and more relevant (if possible) tags to this question, as I couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: Look for the word "parenthesis" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: @BarryCipra - I guess it only makes an assertion on that note. It definitely works, thanks for that :D, but could I have a proof for the same? :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of ways fully to parenthesize a sum of $n+1$ terms (equivalently, a sum with $n$ plus signs). Every fully parenthesized sum has the form $\alpha+\beta$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are either individual variables or fully parenthesized expressions. If there are $k$ plus signs in $\alpha$, there must be $n-1-k$ in $\beta$, where $0\le k\le n-1$. There are then $a_k$ ways to parenthesize $\alpha$ and $a_{n-1-k}$ ways to parenthesize $\beta$, so

$$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_ka_{n-1-k}\;,\tag{1}$$

for $n\ge 1$, and clearly $a_0=1$.

The Catalan numbers satisfy and are commonly defined by the recurrence

$$C_{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^nC_kC_{n-k}\tag{2}$$

for $n\ge 0$ with initial value $C_0=1$. This certainly looks a lot like $(1)$, and if we shift the index down by $1$, it becomes

$$C_n=\sum_{n=0}^{n-1}C_kC_{n-1-k}$$

for $n\ge 1$, still with $C_0=1$. This is identical to $(1)$ apart from the change of $a$ to $C$. That is, the numbers $a_n$ and $C_n$ satisfy the same recurrence with the same initial value, so they must be the same numbers: $a_n=C_n$ for all $n\ge 0$.

If you start with some other definition of the Catalan numbers, you’ll need to prove that that definition implies the recurrence $(2)$.